# legacy listview doesn't touch-scroll

Tags: listview, winapi, touch, atl

I have a problem that verges on the ridiculous. It sounds simple but I have spent a couple of days researching it to no avail.

I have a program in ATL/WTL that uses listview controls to show files and folders. Users are complaining that these panes won't scroll using the "pan" gesture on touch-enabled PCs. It scrolls ok with the mouse, but not with the finger.

The program is completely touch agnostic. It relies on [legacy behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543(v=vs.85).aspx) to translate touch to scroll messages, but it doesn't work. It is hard for me to troubleshoot because **I don't** have a touch capable windows PC to test. I believe scroll messages are sent but then the window jumps back. I don't do any scroll events at all, so it is all default listview behavior.

Other listview controls I use in the same program, e.g. in dialog windows, work properly (!) with touch scrolling. After eliminating all other possibilities, I came to the conclusion that the problem comes from the window class name (?). Whereas the listview windows in dialogs have the default class name `syslistview32`, the views that won't scroll are superclassed in the ATL way:

```
DECLARE_WND_SUPERCLASS(_T("ATL:ShellItemView"), CListViewCtrl::GetWndClassName())
```

however the base class is a standard listview control. Can the problem be the class name?! I can't think of anything else. If you have a touch PC you can try the program from here ([free trial](http://zabkat.com))

thanks
nikos

Comment: Superclassing changes behavior. Have you not considered, that you actively broke the functionality you are after?

Comment: the superclass has the same DefWndProc as a listview control. I only alter the behaviour I need, and that has nothing to do with scrolling. If my hunch is right, whatever is dealing with the touch-to-scroll message translation, looks at the window class name to recognize standard controls

Comment: So now then you know how to construct a [mcve].

Comment: i can see you are a fan of the socratic self-help method :)

Comment: Re: `"I only alter the behaviour I need"` - could you list the messages you handle?

Answer (score 0):

so yes, the class name was it! Instead of superclassing the listview, I created a standard listview and then subclassed it. This preserves the `syslistview32` class name but furnishes my own extra functionality. What's in a name?

this is a big microsoft blunder; I can't believe I lost 3 days on it. But at least now it is solved